# what to put as adunitid in xml layout for android

Tags: android, admob

In admob management AdUnit shows in format
ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/nnnnnnnnnn

How am i suppose to put it in xml layout?

Is this correct?

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/ad1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/nnnnnnnnnn"
/>
```

Comment: Register your app on AdMob and get the ID.

Comment: I have AdUnitId. The question is about AdUnitId format, as i should put it in my app. I am confused by looking here https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/reporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the correct Ad unitId..
It should be something like "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/nnnnnnnnnn"